# how to fix customize select box using css?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to modify a default select box using CSS. I've already done it. But, some problems are happened at firefox. What I've done still now:

[image]
It's the perfect result on all browser except firefox and IE

At firefox, there are the problems:
[image]

(1) There are an unexpected border on the right side of the select box 
(2) Padding of text of select box is much bigger than other input field.

At IE, same problem happened. There are unexpected and much clear box at the right of the select box:
[image]

How can I remove that unexpected line/box from firefox and IE. Also, what can be responsible for the padding problem at firefox?

Well, I've used [this tutorial's concept](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3) to customize the select box using CSS only. And I've put my code at

jsfiddle.net/w9kFc/1/

(I can't add the select-icon image at jsfiddle from external link. So, I've taken the screenshot locally. But, I've given the [image's link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Op9.png) at the jsfiddle code. )

Comment: You could use a HTML if statement and link a "fix" css file to add extra margin/padding to a certain element.

Comment: Firefox 26 here the padding is still messed up, but there is no weird border. Also, that little "unexpected box" is simply the default drop down icon.

Comment: yes, I want to remove that default dropdown icon. for that I wrote on the code, apparence: none; But, it's not worked 100% may be for firefox and IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work in IE10: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgkBn/1/)

Added a `label` around the `select`.
Replaced the `text-indent` with `padding`.